# Accessing a value corresponding to a timestamp from a database returns a Series instead of a single numpy.float64 value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have two codes which are explained in detail below.

Code 1: Reads a .csv file containing timestamp as one column and corresponding values for each timestamp as another column.

Code 2: Reads a database and fetches data from the database having two columns - timestamp as one column and corresponding values for each timestamp as another column.

For Code 1, when I try to access/print the value corresponding to a timestamp, it prints a single numpy.float64 value. This is the way I want my output to be.

However, for Code 2, when I try to print the value corresponding to a timestamp, it prints a Series having one value of object type.

Why is there a difference and what could be causing the difference in outputs even though technically both are dataframes? How do I correct this problem?

Tried the following:

1. Converted the object type to a numpy.float64. Still returns a Series.
2. Read the database, converted it to a .csv format, read the .csv file again and tried accessing. Still returns a Series.

   ```
   from_db = MySQLdb.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", "abcde", "12345", "TABLE_DB")

   sql = "SELECT * FROM `SOME_TABLE` WHERE `THIS IS` = '123456'"

   dmd_data = pd.read_sql(sql, con=from_db)

   dmd_data = dmd_data.NAME

   start_tstamp = '2016-10-08 00:00:00'

   start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_tstamp,f)

   fact1 = (start-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime(f)
   ```

Expected output is:

```
In [53]: dmd_data[fact1]
Out[53]: 4454.82406196

In [67]: type(dmd_data[fact1])
Out[67]: numpy.float64
```

Output I am getting is :

```
In [53]: dmd_data[fact1]
Out[53]: 
TIMESTAMP
2016-10-07    4454.82406196
Name: DEMAND, dtype: object

In [60]: type(data[fact1])
Out[60]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to dataframe:

```
df = series_data.to_frame()
// series_data is your data existing in 'pandas.core.series.Series' object form
```

Now transpose the result

```
df = df.T
```

Now access the value of the corresponding key.
If the problem persists please check the datatype and key of the read data and that you are providing!

Comment: The solution you provided does not work. df[fact1] is still returning a Series and not a single numpy.float64 value.

Comment: can you please share me the screenshot